# why IExtenderProvider Properties are lost in Designer in C# window appliaction?

Tags: c#, winforms, iextenderprovider

I have created a IExtenderProvider (Extender) for Controls.using Extender ,I am Iterating the collection of controls and validate it.It works fine.but, some time while changing some designs,or when designer refreshed (while removing some events from code), the properties that provided by Extender (Validation Order and Group,in my case) are getting lost from designer and the **control itself  is not added** into Extender collection.so, The validation done by application collapsed (and, of course, application itself ).I have ShouldSerialize and Reset Methods in IExtenderProvider too.but nothing helped me.Please guide me how make all controls visible to extender at all times.

Thanks,
Mathi

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens when there is an exception in the Extender. If this happens, you will need to debug your extender in design-time. I had to do this several times today. Check out [Debugging Design-Time Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996457.aspx), it should get you started

Other times this happens because you have changed properties and methods of the Extender and the "serialize" values are no longer appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This article titled "[Bending the code generation of IExtenderProvider to your will](http://www.timvw.be/2007/08/21/bending-the-code-generation-of-iextenderprovider-to-your-will/)" by Tim Van Wassenhove may have a solution that is related to your problem. It describes building a custom serializer for your IExtenderProvider implementation which, in doing so may alleviate the issue stated here.

Most of the relevant information from the article was also quoted in [another answer here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21760381/16387).

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is definetly to late for the OP, but might help others.

I had the same problem: properties were either lost or didn't show up at all. In my case the problem was, that the type specified with ProvideProperty, CanExtend and the SetXXX and GetXX methods were not the same. For example ProvideProperty and CanExtend specified 'Control' as type, but the SetXXX and GetXXX mehtods specified 'object' as first parameter.

So, as soon as I made sure, that for **each and every** type specified in ProvideProperty I had a matching GetXXX and SetXXX, everything worked as expected.

Maybe this helps.

Note: After fixing the code I had to restart Visual Studio.